# <ResponsiveContainer> in Recharts is not rendering

Tags: html, css, reactjs, recharts

I'm trying to use a **lineChart** from **Recharts** in my react app. But while I'm using the `</ResponsiveContainer>` the line chart is not getting rendered.
Here is my code:

```
 <div class className='line-container'>
    <ResponsiveContainer width="100%" height="100%">
       <LineChart
        width={1200}
        height={300}
        data={fruits}>
           <CartesianGrid strokeDasharray="1 3" />
           <XAxis dataKey="name" />
           <YAxis />
           <Tooltip />
           <Legend />
           <Line type="monotone" dataKey="quantity" stroke="#8884d8" />
       </LineChart>
   </ResponsiveContainer>
 </div>
```

**Note:** It works without the `</ResponsiveContainer>`. But What changes should be made to make it work with `</ResponsiveContainer>`

Answer (score 0):

set the ResponsiveContainer heights like heights={300/500} and keep the width as 100% then it will work properly!

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).